# Read very huge csv file in chunks using generators and pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, generator

I have a very huge CSVs of 40ishGB , how I can read it chunk by chunk and add a column with value "today's date".

Approaches I tried is directly reading and my system crashed.
Then I used `chunks in pd.read_csv` which is well one solution to it.

I was wondering if someone suggests a way how we can use generators to do this and add the column to every chunk?

Comment: Chunking is an idea, generators are more of a specific technology. What I hear you saying is, "I want to read in the CSV, add a column, and write the new CSV out; and all with a low memory footprint, so my computer doesn't crash". And you want to add single, "constant", value? To how many rows?

Comment: @ZachYoung Yes, 
"I want to read in the CSV, add a column, and write the new CSV out; and all with a low memory footprint, so my computer doesn't crash
and  "constant" value for a column should be added to all rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `pd.read_csv` with `chunksize` is already quite like using a `generator`.

This will add a new column to the end, and assign a value of `1` to each row for the column.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as fin, open('test_output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    line = fin.readline()
    fout.write(line.rstrip('\n') + ',new_column\n')
    
    while True:
        line = fin.readline()
        if line:
            fout.write(line.rstrip('\n') + ',1\n')
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Will above code work if input file has blank lines? like
-------Header----
line 2 :abcabc
line 3: edfedf
line 4 :<empty>
line 5 :<empty>
line 6 : RestofFile

?

Comment: @user76170, yes. an empty line is not empty, it has at least a '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) based example:

```py
from datetime import date

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=True).update(
    **{"name of the new column": date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}
).into_csv("output.csv")
```

It will process the stream from one file to another, applying the transformation in the middle.